# Ionic 2: How to bind <ion-select> to an option's key?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm developing my first Ionic 2 app. I have an `<ion-select>` with a dynamic option list. That list is represented in my component as a simple dictionary (named `stateOptions`):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './test.html'
})
export class TestPage {

    stateOptions: {
        al: 'Alabama',
        ak: 'Alaska',
        az: 'Arizona',
        ar: 'Arkansas'
    }

    customer: {
        street_address: '123 Sunshine Lane',
        city: 'Phoenix',
        state: 'az'
    }

}
```

In my view, I would like to configure the `<ion-select>` so that `customer.state` gets set to the selected state's key. So, for example, if the user selects "Arkansas" from the dropdown, the value of `customer.state` would become the string "ar". **How can I achieve this?**

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>State</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="customer.state">
        <ion-option *ngFor="???"></ion-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>

<p>Current value of customer.state: {{ customer.state }}</p>
```

In Angular 1, this is easily accomplished with the ngOptions directive:

```
<select ng-model="customer.state" ng-options="abbr as name for ( abbr, name ) in stateOptions"></select>
```

...but it seems like `<ion-select>` doesn't support this.

**Here's one solution I've seen:** At init time, convert `stateOptions` into a format that's easier to work with. In the component, I can do this:

```
stateOptionsFormatted: Array<Object> = [];

constructor() {
    for (var key in this.stateOptions) {
        this.stateOptionsFormatted.push({
            abbr: key,
            name: this.stateOptions[key]
        });
    }
}
```

And in the view:

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="customer.state">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let stateOption of stateOptionsFormatted" [value]="stateOption.abbr">{{ stateOption.name }}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

This works, but it's extra boilerplate code to achieve something that's a one-liner in Angular 1.

I also saw a solution which involves a custom pipe to do this conversion in the view - but others said that this would be bad for performance, since it would get run many times as the user interacts with the page.

Is there a better option? There will be many `<ion-select>`s throughout my app, so I'd prefer something clean and concise if it's available.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys()` as in

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="customer.state">
    <ion-option *ngFor="let key of stateOptionKeys"></ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

And define `stateOptionKeys` inside the component's `ngOnInit()` method as,

```
this.stateOptionKeys = Object.keys(this.stateOption);
```

You also have to declare `stateOptionKeys` as an `array`-property of the component class.

Comment: Thanks for this! This is what I ended up doing. It's still a bit more boilerplate than I prefer, but it seems to be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me :

```
<ion-select cancelText="cancel" okText="ok" [(ngModel)]="model.cityid" name="cityid">
    <ion-select-option [(value)]="city.id" *ngFor="let city of cities">{{city.title}}</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```